# Derivative of the $dh(x)Ax$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Given a function $h:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $ and a matrix $A$ what it is the derivative of
$dh(x)Ax$ ? That is how calculate $d(dh(x)Ax)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\phi(x) := Dh_x(Ax)$ (the subscript is simply to indicate the base point of the derivative). Think of this like a "product" between $Dh_x$ and $Ax$. More precisely, we consider the evaluation map $\text{ev}: L(\Bbb{R}^n) \times \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$ given by $(T,v) \mapsto T(v)$. Then,
\begin{align}
\phi(x) &= \text{ev}(Dh_x, Ax)
\end{align}
It is easy to see that $\text{ev}$ is a bilinear (and continuous, since the vector spaces are all finite-dimensional); i.e it is a "product" of some kind. So, there is a natural product rule in this case:
\begin{align}
D\phi_x(\cdot) &= \text{ev}(D^2h_x(\cdot), Ax) + \text{ev}(Dh_x, A(\cdot))
\end{align}
Notice what I did; I simply "differentiated the first term, kept the second one alone, then leave the first alone, and differentiate the second". The $(\cdot)$ notation means given $v \in \Bbb{R}^n$, that's where you plug it in (recall that derivatives are linear transformations, so they can be evaluated on some vector). So, for all $v \in \Bbb{R}^n$ (by unwinding the definition of ev):
\begin{align}
D\phi_x(v) &= (D^2h_x[v])[Ax] + Dh_x[Av] \\
&= D^2h_x[v,Ax] + Dh_x[Av]
\end{align}
where in the final line, I'm simply using the fact that the second derivative at a point $D^2h_x$ can be equivalently thought of as a linear map $\Bbb{R}^n \to L(\Bbb{R}^n)$, or as a bilinear map $\Bbb{R}^n \times \Bbb{R}^n \to \Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: So one can say " brutally" that $d(dh(x)Ax)=d^2hAx +dh(x)A$ ?

Comment: @GiovanniFebbraro sure... I guess if you want to go that far to suppress where things are being evaluated.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot @peek-a-boo